# How to create Global authority for pool

Tags: anchor, rust

I am trying to create a functionality where the admin can fund SPL tokens in the pool and any other user can claim from that pool.

I am using global authority as the authority for the pool address

```
pub struct CreateTweet<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(init, payer = user, seeds = [b"tweets", user.key().as_ref(), &[my_id as u8], &[my_id2 as u8]], bump, space = 64,)]
    pub tweetData: Account<'info, MyTweet>,
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [GLOBAL_AUTHORITY_SEED.as_ref()],
        bump = global_bump,
    )]
    pub global_authority: Account<'info, GlobalPool>,
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = user,
        seeds = [b"pool", user.key().as_ref(), tweetData.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
        token::mint = pool_mint,
        token::authority = global_authority,
    )]
    pub pool: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user_ata: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    pub pool_mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
}
```

this is my function where I am transferring SPL tokens from pool to user token account

```
    let seeds = &[GLOBAL_AUTHORITY_SEED.as_bytes(), &[global_bump]];
        let signer = &[&seeds[..]];

        
        
        token::transfer(
            CpiContext::new_with_signer(
                ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
                token::Transfer {
                    from: ctx.accounts.pool.to_account_info(),
                    to: ctx.accounts.user_ata.to_account_info(),
                    authority: ctx.accounts.global_authority.to_account_info(),
                },
                signer
            ),
            1000000000
        )?;
```

But it is giving me an Error with code 0xbbf:

Error: **#[msg("The given account is owned by a different program than expected")]
AccountOwnedByWrongProgram**

*Also, the pool address is owned by the same address created with global authority seeds*

Global authority address:
https://explorer.solana.com/address/3Z3vN7UUoDcCWpYksnM5nj7BHgERQKhbKTEEXnnratk6?cluster=devnet

Pool (account) address:
https://explorer.solana.com/address/FyJWLhuZase1mVpVraRHU6HBav9heHmS1Bu28NckRfSj?cluster=devnet

Comment: can you provide the context where you have initialized global_authority?

Answer (score 1):

Your seeds for global_authority in the validator are `[GLOBAL_AUTHORITY_SEED.as_ref()]`. Your signer seeds are `[GLOBAL_AUTHORITY_SEED.as_bytes()]`. These don't match and that's why you're getting that error.

**Update**
If you absolutely have to, here's to declare a constant you intend to use as one of the seeds of a PDA:

```
const GLOBAL_AUTHORITY_SEED: &[u8] = "global-authority".as_bytes();
```

and in your validator:

```
seeds=[GLOBAL_AUTHORITY_SEED]
```

Comment: Switching as_bytes to as_ref it is giving error on compilation time:

expected reference `&[&[&[u8]]]`
found reference `&[&[&[u8; 1]]; 1]`

also, have tried using as_byte on both sides.
same results for me.

Comment: What is your 'GLOBAL_AUTHORITY_SEED'?

Comment: its string:
pub const GLOBAL_AUTHORITY_SEED: &str = "global-authority";

Comment: In that case your seeds should be `[GLOBAL_AUTHORITY_SEED].as_bytes().as_ref()`

Comment: Just tried it ... but same error..!!

Comment: Oh! The problem is defining GLOBAL_AUTHORITY_SEEDS as a &str. Change the definition to `pub const GLOBAL_AUTHORITY_SEED: &[u8] = "global-authority".as_bytes()`. Then in the validator your seed would simply be `GLOBAL_AUTHORITY_SEED`.

Comment: not working, facing the same error. any other way to give global authority?

Comment: Send your new const definition, and also your seeds for global_authority in the validator. Did you rebuild and redeploy?

Comment: yes... rebuilding and redeploying after every change... pub const GLOBAL_AUTHORITY_SEED: &[u8] = "global-authority".as_bytes();
and, 
seeds = &[GLOBAL_AUTHORITY_SEED];

Comment: What about in your validator?